# Tuples of dictionary in python

Tags: python, dictionary, tuples

Given a dictionary

```
{4: {'idx': [45, 177, 181],
    'Baggage': array([ 13, 103,  87]),
    'infeed_idx': array([1, 3, 3])},
 7: {'idx': [62, 105, 173, 174, 186, 57, 74, 102, 115, 164],
      'Baggage': array([12, 27, 50, 51, 16, 30, 15, 59, 16,  8]),
      'infeed_idx': array([1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2])},
```

I would like to create a tuple of idx and infeed_idx (45,1), (177,3).

Expected output

```
{4: {'idx': [45, 177, 181],
    'Baggage': array([ 13, 103,  87]),
    'infeed_idx': array([1, 3, 3])},
    'tuple_id': [(45,1),(177,3),(177,3)]
 7: {'idx': [62, 105, 173, 174, 186, 57, 74, 102, 115, 164],
      'Baggage': array([12, 27, 50, 51, 16, 30, 15, 59, 16,  8]),
      'infeed_idx': array([1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2])},
      'tuple_id': [(62,1),(105,1),(173,1),(174,1),(186,1),(57,2),(74,2),(102,2),(115,2),(164,2)]
```

I hope you guys can help!

Answer (score 1):

Let's say `dct` is your dictionary:

```
for k, d in dct.items():
    d['tuple_id'] = list(zip(d['idx'], d['infeed_idx']))
```

Comment: Thanks a lot - did exactly as expected!

Answer (score 1):

```
di = {4: {'idx': [45, 177, 181],
    'Baggage': np.array([ 13, 103,  87]),
    'infeed_idx': np.array([1, 3, 3])}, 
        7: {'idx': [62, 105, 173, 174, 186, 57, 74, 102, 115, 164],
        'Baggage': np.array([12, 27, 50, 51, 16, 30, 15, 59, 16,  8]),
        'infeed_idx': np.array([1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2])}}

for key, value in di.items():
    value['infeed_idx'] = list(zip(value['idx'], value['infeed_idx']))
    
print(di)
```

You can get the job done with a simple for loop. I hope it was helpful.

Answer (score 0):

just use `zip` function

```
>>> x = [1, 2, 3]
>>> y = [4, 5, 6]
>>> zipped = zip(x, y)
>>> list(zipped)
[(1, 4), (2, 5), (3, 6)]
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try

```
d = {4: {'idx': [45, 177, 181],
    'Baggage': array([ 13, 103,  87]),
    'infeed_idx': array([1, 3, 3])},
 7: {'idx': [62, 105, 173, 174, 186, 57, 74, 102, 115, 164],
      'Baggage': array([12, 27, 50, 51, 16, 30, 15, 59, 16,  8]),
      'infeed_idx': array([1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2])}
      }
for k in d:
    d[k]["tuple_id"] = list(zip(d[k]['idx'], d[k]['infeed_idx']))
```